# `[1] == [1]` is valid Swift but `[[1]] == [[1]]` doesn't compile. Why?

Tags: swift

In Swift, this compiles without error:

```
[1] == [1]
```

However, if I try to compile:

```
[[1]] == [[1]]
```

I get the error:

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[Array<Int>]' operands
```

Is this expected? Is this just an omission in the standard library, or is it hard to provide this in a generic way?